# Serial Comunication via Python

Tags: python, serial-port, teraterm

I'm trying to write a command and read how the system reply to it.
The code I've done is the following:

```
import serial
import time
import sys

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 38400, timeout=1)
print(ser.name)  
msg = 'show interfaces status ethernet 0/1'
ser.write((msg.encode()))

time.sleep(0.5)
res=ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
print ((res.decode()))
ser.close()
```

doing so I have no error but the output I see is this:

> COM5
> show interfaces status ethernet 0/1

Using TeraTerm and with the same setup and the same command I see instead the reply of the system which show the status of the ethernet port.

The only difference I could notice is that in Teraterm the command line is with "Console#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there were two errors in my previous attempt:
1- I was missing the "enter" once I've written the command (so the +'\r')
2- I need also a loop in order to read all the information

this is how I've done in the end:

```
import serial
import time



#ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 38400, timeout=1)
ser = serial.Serial()
#ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.port = "COM5"
ser.baudrate = 38400





try: 
    ser.open()
    print(ser.name) 
except:
    print ("Errore apertura porta seriale" )
    exit()


if ser.isOpen():
         ser.flushInput()
         ser.flushOutput()
         msg = 'show interfaces status ethernet 0/1'+'\r'
         ser.write((msg.encode()))
         time.sleep(0.5)
         while 1:
            bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
            print (bytesToRead)
            out=ser.read(bytesToRead)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(out.decode())
            if bytesToRead>=255:
                break
           
    
ser.close()
```

as I said I'm not a programmer...so I'm 100% this can be done better...but it worked for me.